# Interpreting standard deviation ratio (is std deviation ratio equal to coefficient of variation?)

Tags: standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

I am new in this area. I apologizes if my question is silly.

I need to include the homogeneity and heterogeneity of variance as one of the factor in my robustness study.Therefore, i saw this phrase. And after searching online for days, I seldom found its related information. Is "standard deviation ratio " means the compare of 2 sample's standard deviation ratio? For example, if I set the standard deviation ratio as 1.00, then it will be A:1 B:1 ..? or if i set the ratio as 2.5 then A=5 B=2? Is this concept correct?

add on:

Now i am wondering do standard deviation ratio is actually EQUAL to coefficient of variation which is the ratio of 2 std deviation with different means.?

https://www.colby.edu/math/program/honorsprojects/2013-Cleveland-Honors.pdf
This is the article that i am referring.

Comment: I don't see how we can easily comment on the standard deviation ratio, which comes from sources you do not specify. But the coefficient of variation is not at all the ratio of two standard deviations with different means. It is just standard deviation/mean, and often expressed as a percentage.

Comment: hi, Nick, I am really quick confusing about this standard deviation ratio ....since the journal that i am referring, the author is stating the std deviation ratio in value (1, 1.1, 1.25,1.5, 2.0) ,but i do not know how do interpret it in terms of 2 sample standard deviation..

Comment: Add on: now i have to conduct simulation study on their robustness on the violation of assumptions on 2 gamma distribution with equal and unequal skewness , so i need to interpret the scale parameter (require standard deviation) but i do not know how is it going to work...@@

Comment: I can't see your source. Presumably the argument is that only the ratio of two standard deviations matters.

Comment: ermm...so can i concluded the ratio of 2 standard deviation as the way we computed the ratio of 2 compared items?

Comment: for example , if A is 2, B is 1 , then the ratio shall be 2/1=2

Comment: This is the article that i am referring.... https://www.colby.edu/math/program/honorsprojects/2013-Cleveland-Honors.pdf

Comment: Please edit the link into your question

Comment: I am sorry ...edited.:)